# Generics basic usage

Tags: c#, generics

I keep using the function below in my classes and would like to write it as generics.

```
public static IEnumerable<MyObject> Get(string csvFile)
{
    return csvFile
        .ReadAsStream()
        .SplitCrLf()
        .Where(row => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row))
        .Select(row => new MyObject(row.Split(',')));
}
```

I scratch the code below but didn't work

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Get<T>(string csvFile)
{
    return csvFile
        .ReadAsStream()
        .SplitCrLf()
        .Where(row => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row))
        .Select(row => new typeof(T)(row.Split(',')));
}
```

Please advise.  Thank you!

Comment: Didn't work, in what way?

Comment: Presumably didn't compile, because `new typeof(T)` is invalid syntax.

Comment: You can generate a `IEnumerable<string>` from the csv file. To convert that to an `IEnumerable<T>` you will need to define a conversion function `Func<string,T>` and apply it.

Comment: So is each row a `MyObject` or each element a `MyObject`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot use `new` to create instances using generic types in this way<sup>1</sup>.  Consider supplying a factory delegate to the function:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Get<T>(string csvFile, Func<string[], T> factory)
{
    return csvFile
        .ReadAsStream()
        .SplitCrLf()
        .Where(row => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row))
        .Select(row => factory(row.Split(',')));
}
```

Then you would call it like so:

```
var myObjects = Get("file.csv", row => new MyObject(row));
```

Alternatively, you can return an `IEnumerable<string[]>`<sup>2</sup> and let the caller decide what to do with it:

```
public static IEnumerable<string[]> Get(string csvFile)
{
    return csvFile
        .ReadAsStream()
        .SplitCrLf()
        .Where(row => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row))
        .Select(row => row.Split(','));
}
```

Then the caller could do:

```
var myObjects = Get("file.csv").Select(row => new MyObject(row));
```

---

<sup>1</sup>You can supply the `where T : new()` constraint and then you can create new instances using a generic type, but only when it provides a no-argument constructor; you cannot provide arguments when constructing generic types, and your use case appears to require it.  A factory delegate is your best option here.

For reference, this is how construction using generic types would look in the no-argument case:

```
public static T Create<T>() where T : new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

<sup>2</sup>Even better would be an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` assuming that your `MyObject` constructor accepts `IEnumerable<string>` as well.

Comment: although, there is the [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx). Nice suggestions though, +1

Comment: @Default Indeed there is.  In fact, `new T()` is compiled as `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`.  However, one should note that this technique (using CreateInstance to pass arguments to a constructor) will use reflection each time, incurring a potentially serious performance penalty.  Using a factory delegate not only gives more flexibility (maybe you want to do more than just construct an object) while also making use of compiled code and avoiding the cost of reflection.

Comment: great addition! I didn't know that.

Comment: does `default(T)` also compile to `Activator`?

Comment: @Default No; the value of `default(T)` is determined only once for each `T`, when a constructed generic type is instantiated at runtime.  It will be replaced with a constant value at that time.  For example, if `T` is `int` then the IL representation of `default(T)` will be `ldc.i4.0` (a literal `0` constant) in the constructed type.  For all reference types, it will be `ldnull` (a literal `null` constant).  For structs, it will be `new StructType()`, which effectively just zeroes a chunk of memory. tl;dr version: there is no reflection overhead with `default(T)`.

Comment: @Default If you want to go to a lower level, `default(T)` effectively means "a chunk of memory the size of `T` where all bits are zero." :)